# Wouldn't Arthur Tressler's bank return all of his money under the circumstances?

Tags: now-you-see-me

In the movie "Now You See Me", during the second magic show, the Four Horseman steal all of Arthur Tressler's money and give it away to people who had previously held insurance agreements with one of Arthur's companies that had refused to pay out after a natural disaster.

I'm no expert on the American banking system, but surely in the instance where something like this happened, with the FBI watching it happen and confirming it had happened, the banks would reverse all of the transactions and return all of Arthur Tressler's money to him?

Wouldn't Arthur Tressler's bank return all of his money under the circumstances?

Comment: I've not seen the show, but I think your trust in banks is ..astonishing.  They have 101 ways to say 'not our problem, not paying'.  And depending on the 'goodwill' of the bank?  Bwaa-ha-ha..  that's just funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bank accounts in the US (I *believe* this was a US bank, but not sure) are covered under an insurance provided by the [FDIC](http://www.fdic.gov/deposit/deposits/dis/). Assuming all of his money was in one account, as seems the case, the deposit would only have been covered for $250,000. From a realism point of view, no person with that sort of money would have kept all of their money in one account or one location. They would be highly diversified, not only from an earnings side of things, but from a safety side of things to prevent just this sort of action.

As far as the "FBI watching it happen", since Rhodes is the lead investigator and the instigator, he would not have pursued any action which would interrupt that plan. He either would not have provided any information or would have conveniently destroyed any information garnered from the investigation. He had put too much time and effort into the entire scheme and would not have any bit of it fall apart in the end.

Comment: Sorry for years long necro, but I just saw the movie and I think this is wrong. FDIC is primarily for great depression, run-on-the-bank style situations where the bank literally is out of money. What happened here was theft, and more over it was clear where the money went to. What would actually happen is that all transactions would be voided and the money would be returned from the audience to Tressler